# Algebraic Group with two components over algebraically closed field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I want to find an algebraic group with two components over, say, $\mathbb{C}$ for simplicity. This more or less means that we want an index 2 subgroup. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_group#Glossary_of_algebraic_groups) says that the character group $X^*(\mathbb{G}_m) \approx \mathbb{Z}$, so this should work since we have the subgroup $2\mathbb{Z}$. However, I do not understand why this is correct (I think the isomorphism is true since all of the maps are power maps of some degree) - in particular, a variety should be the zero locus of a *finite* set of (*finite* degree) polynomials, so I do not see how $\mathbb{Z}$, or even $\text{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$, could satisfy this.

Comment: Would the group of $2\times2$-matrices $X$ such that $\det(X)^2=1$ fit the bill? Adjust size of the matrices to your liking.

Comment: @jgon Sorry, I meant 2$\mathbb{Z}$ - will correct it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, this works!

Comment: You could take the constant group $\underline{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}$.